# Is it possible to have variable find conditions for both the key and value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass in both the field and the value in a find call:

```
@employee = Employee.find(:all,
              :conditions => [ '? = ?', params[:key], params[:value].to_i)
```

The output is

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE ('is_manager' = 1)
```

Which returns no results, however when I try this directly in mysqsl using the same call without the '' around is_manager, it works fine.  How do I convert my params[:key] value to a symbol so that the resulting SQL call looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE (is_manager = 1)
```

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use variable substitution for column name instead of using bind values:

```
# make sure the key passed is a valid column
if Employee.columns_hash[params[:key]]
  Employee.all :conditions => [ "#{params[:key]} = ?", params[:value]]
end
```

You can further secure the solution by ensuring column name passed belongs to a pre selected set.:

```
if ["first_name", "last_name"].include? [params[:key]]
  Employee.all :conditions => [ "#{params[:key]} = ?", params[:value]]
end
```

Comment: This is a generic solution. User can have a valid keys hash and use that for validation (instead of columns_hash). His original issue is due to the fact the col name was substituted using the bind variables and rails surrounded the col names with quotes. This will not be addressed by passing a symbol (instead of string) for col name parameter. I added `columns_hash` validation as a guide line for adding a check to limit the column names to a known set. That should the security issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert a string to symbol(which is what params[:key] produces, all you need to do is

```
params[:key].to_s.to_sym
```

2 points:

1. A word of caution : symbols are
   not garbage collected.
2. Make sure your key is not a
   number, if you convert to_s first
   then to_sym, your code will work but
   you may get a wierd symbol like
   this:

   `:"5"`

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'm afraid I asked the wrong question perhaps.  


@employee = Employee.find(:all,
              :conditions => [ '? = ?', params[:key].to_s.to_sym, params[:value].to_i)

Produces the following SQL output:

SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE ('--- :is_manager\n' = 1)


I think I must have a error in my logic rather than syntax.  I could do a case statement where I check what the params[:key] is and do the appropriate find (in this case it would be [:is_manager = ?, params[:value].to_i]).  

But I was hoping to be a bit more dynamic and not have to redo each case individually.

Comment: I kind of answered what you asked, not what you meant :-) I'm not sure what you ask for is possible or most importantly - desired, at least not according to rails spec http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html . The problem is that it's a potential big security hole. Assume this is an HR application: what if somebody will pass for a key = salary. Then they can potentially pull salary info or ssn info for any  person. I mean sure you could put all sort of role-based security, but that would defeat the purpose of saving  you time you would spent writing out your case statement.

Comment: Gotcha.  The key is coming from a select box, so I'm only accepting specific values (plus I'm authenticating as this is an 'admin' tool).  But I hear ya.  Case statement it is :)

Answer (score 1):

"string".to_sym